# MS SQL: query multiple tables

Tags: sql-server

Consider the three tables with the following structure and entries:

```
project
-------
projectGuid | projectName | emailEmployer | emailEmployee
________________________________________________________
AB          | tiger       | xyz@mail.com  | NULL
CD          | snake       | NULL          | abc@mail.com


projectHistory
--------------
historyGuid | projectGuid | historyTimestamp | statusId
_______________________________________________________
ST          | AB          | 2015-08-11 15:18:09.047 | 1
UV          | AB          | 2015-08-16 15:20:10.100 | 2
WX          | CD          | 2015-07-12 15:04:03.018 | 1


status
------
statusId | statusDisplay
________________________
1        | created
2        | start
```

How does the query look like to achieve the following output:

```
projectGuid | projectName | emailEmployer | emailEmployee | historyTimestamp | statusId | statusDisplay
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________
AB          | tiger       | xyz@mail.com  | NULL          | 2015-08-16 15:20:10.100 | 2 | start
CD          | snake       | NULL          | abc@mail.com  | 2015-07-12 15:04:03.018 | 1 | created
```

Given is the attribut `emailEmployer` **OR** `emailEmployee` and I only want the last `historyTimestamp` of a project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along the lines of this should do the trick:

```
SELECT p.projectGuid
     , p.projectName
     , p.emailEmployer
     , p.emailEmployee
     , ph.historyTimestamp
     , s.statusId
     , s.statusDisplay
  FROM project p
  JOIN (SELECT projectGuid
             , MAX(historyTimestamp) AS historyTimestamp
             , MAX(statusId) AS statusId
          FROM projectHistory           
      GROUP BY projectGuid) ph
    ON p.projectGuid = ph.projectGuid
  JOIN status s
    ON ph.statusId = s.statusId
 WHERE (p.emailEmployer = @email OR p.emailEmployee = @email)
```

@email is the parameter for the email attribute.

Comment: SSMS displays the following error message: "The multi-part identifier `ph.statusId` could not be bound.". Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use `CTE` or a `subquery` to do this:

**Subquery:**

```
DECLARE @email varchar(255);

SELECT p.projectguid
    ,p.projectname
    ,p.emailEmployer
    ,p.emailEmployee
    ,ph.historyTimestamp
    ,ph.statusid
    ,s.statusDisplay
FROM project p
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT projectguid
        ,max(historyTimestamp) AS historyTimestamp
        ,max(statusid) AS statusid
    GROUP BY projectguid
    ) ph ON ph.projectguid = p.projectguid
INNER JOIN [status] s ON s.statusid = ph.statusid
WHERE (p.emailEmployer = @email OR p.emailEmployee = @email)
```

**CTE:**

```
DECLARE @email varchar(255);

;with ph as
 (SELECT projectguid
        ,max(historyTimestamp)
        ,max(statusid) AS statusid AS historyTimestamp
    GROUP BY projectguid
  )
SELECT p.projectguid
    ,p.projectname
    ,p.emailEmployer
    ,p.emailEmployee
    ,ph.historyTimestamp
    ,ph.statusid
    ,s.statusDisplay
FROM project p
INNER JOIN ph ON ph.projectguid = p.projectguid
INNER JOIN [status] s ON s.statusid = ph.statusid
WHERE (p.emailEmployer = @email OR p.emailEmployee = @email)
```